# Braket notation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, braket

I am using the [`braket`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/braket) package to generate bra and ket vectors. However, I could not figure out how to do `<0|0>` using the package. Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `\braket{0|0}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

$\braket{0|0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 78):

<s>There is the [`physics`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics) package:</s>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  $\bra{\Psi}\ket{\Psi}$ $\expval{A}{\Psi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

<s>It offers many other goodies for typsetting physics things. Details can be found in the manul (`texdoc physics` from command prompt/terminal).</s>

**Edit by @Gaussler in 2023:** **Do not use the `physics` package at all**. To quote Henri Menke’s comment below, “[t]he implementation is really horrible and it destroys the spacing all over the place.” To put it differently, `physics` belongs together with `commath` in package hell. Use one of the solutions from the other answers instead.

Comment: I love you man, I had a lot of stuff the package implements, defined manually.

Comment: **Do not use the `physics` package.** The implementation is really horrible and it destroys the spacing all over the place.

Comment: And whoever reads this, please downvote this answer.

Answer (score 51):

A solution using the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \bra{a}       &= \bra*{\frac{a}{1}} \\
  \ket{a}       &= \ket*{\frac{a}{1}} \\
  \braket{a}{b} &= \braket*{\frac{a}{1}}{\frac{b}{1}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that the starred versions of the macros scale automatically.

Comment: Hope one of a better suggestion...

Comment: And it works for MathJax!

Comment: Adapted from section 3.6 of the docs, it's best to add `\mathopen{}` after `\vert`: `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}`. Otherwise \braket{a}{-b} will typeset `| - b` as if it's subtracting b, instead of `| -b`.

Comment: @anderium Thanks! I've updated the answer according to your suggestion. (I don't know why this hasn't happened before.)

Answer (score 38):

You can use the `\langle` and `\rangle` commands. For example, to do `<0|0>`, you would do:

```
\langle 0 | 0 \rangle
```

Result:

[image]

If you have things which use vertical space (like fractions), you can use `\left`, `\right` and `\middle` to adjust the vertical size of the `<`, `>` and `|` symbols. For example:

```
\left\langle \frac{1}{2} \middle| 1 \right\rangle
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know the existence of \middle! thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the \middle

Comment: That \middle was my salvation, thank you

Answer (score 8):

A complement to the answers above. In case one wants to have a different operators in the left/right and want something in the middle the `\expval` does no help. An option is to use the `\matrixelement` in the `physics` package.
This also have the advantage of the proper scaling of the bras & kets for disproportional  operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \mel{n}{A}{m}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: **Do not use the `physics` package.** The implementation is really horrible and it destroys the spacing all over the place.

Comment: Despite I did not have problems with the `physics` package, I can't disagree with you as i never check the implementation. If I found another formulation that solves the problem in such simple manner and has a better implementation, I will definitely update. Meanwhile we have your warning for anyone who may need/want to use it.

Comment: Actually, the construct in the example you show already destroys the spacing.  Try `\fbox{$\mel{n}{A}{m}$}` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3blj.png)).  You can see that there is more space on the left than on the right, which comes from the fact that the implementation of `physics` is utter garbage.

Comment: @HenriMenke What alternative do you advise?

Comment: @Andrea I think you probably found your answers already, but since I stumbled upon this question now and use `maththools` package I noramlly have nowadays:


`\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\ketbra[2]{\lvert}{\rvert}{#1\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle#2}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\projector[1]{\lvert}{\rvert}{#1\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle#1}%`