# Punctuation spacing in math that ends with a differential \dd{}, and the physics package

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation, physics, integral

It seems the physics package adds an extra (thin) space after `\dd{x}`, before my punctuation (usually "," or ".") and I don't want this. This is a common scenario for me, especially if I'm displaying a calculation that ends in an integral.  It seems that I can get around this by sticking the punctuation into the `\dd` command, like so: `\dd{x.}`. I've used a regex to replace this in my document, but is there a way to get `physics` get this right automatically? This is probably the only feature of the `physics` package that I use, and while googling, I saw that a Henri Menke [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex) in a comment

> Do not use the physics package. The implementation is really horrible and it destroys the spacing all over the place.

...so if there is a good way to automatically have thin spaces at the *correct* places without the `physics` package, I'm all game.

A simple MWE so you can see what I mean (I don't usually punctuate inside inline math mode)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}    
\begin{document}
$A \dd{s}.$ 
\[ B \dd{s}.\] 
$C \dd{s.}$
\[ D \dd{s.}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` (I'd prefer without the `\mathrm`, but the document is yours). Whether you type `\dd s` or `\dd{s}` it doesn't matter. The `physics` package is full of dubious constructions.

Comment: @egreg that works very nicely, thank you! While trying to understand how it works, I came across an answer of yours that in the process of explaining `\mathop`, gave this exact solution - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84302/what-is-the-difference-of-mathop-operatorname-and-declaremathoperator If this counts as a duplicate then close away, otherwise in the near future I will summarise the relevant information into an answer...