# Large vertical lines in braket notation are too thick when using Asana Math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, braket, asana

For creating braket notation within my formulas, I tried using the following two approaches:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214730/205359 (Braket package)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214825/205359 (Mathtools approach)

Although, when using the math font "Asana Math" and XeTeX, the following happens to larger braket formulas:

[image]

As you can see, the vertical lines are abnormally thick. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Style=Alternate]{Asana Math}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\vert #2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketdouble[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\lvert #2 \delimsize\rvert #3}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\braketdouble*{\psi }{ {\sum_i{\ket{i}\bra{i}}} }{ \psi}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only are they too thick, they're also too tall.  It looks like a smaller vert has been scaled uniformly instead of using a glyph directly from a font or scaling only vertically.  I don't know anything about `\delimsize`, but I'd look at that as the culprit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually you get the same with a simple  `\left| ...\right|` the extension pieces for a vertical bar are just a lot wider than the stadard size bar, whether by design or by error I am not sure,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, that's why I wrote that I tried it with different approaches (that both seem to have the same effect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can borrow `\vert` from another font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Style=Alternate]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=\vert]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range=]{Asana Math}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \,\delimsize\vert\, #2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketdouble[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{%
  #1 \,\delimsize\vert\, #2 \,\delimsize\vert\, #3%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\braketdouble[\bigg]{\psi }{ {\sum_i{\ket{i}\bra{i}}} }{ \psi}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't use `*` in this case, that makes too big fences.

Comment: hmm probably better, especially if you need to do the same with any other characters where a rule can't be used as an easy alternative

Comment: Why do you have to put `\setmathfont[range=]{Asana Math}` again?

Comment: @TiMauzi it's a "feature" of unicode-math range feature that it's more reliable if you specify the main font in the final range

Comment: Okay, this approach worked perfectly! I just added `\Vert` to the respective range, so the style of both double and single vertical lines are the same: `\setmathfont[range={\vert,\Vert}]{STIX Two Math}`.

Comment: @TiMauzi It makes sense indeed!

Answer (score 4):

The font just has very wide | extension parts specified, but you could use a rule instead

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Style=Alternate]{Asana Math}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\vert #2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketdouble[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\lvert #2 \delimsize\rvert #3}

\begin{document}

\[
\braketdouble*{\psi }{ {\sum_i{\ket{i}\bra{i}}} }{ \psi}
\]
\[
\Uleft<\psi\vline width .9pt \sum_i \lvert i\rangle\langle  i\rvert \vline width .9pt \psi\Uright>
\]
\end{document}
```