# Error in Wick contraction

Tags: errors, compilation-error, simplewick

I am getting the following error:

"Package simpler-wick Warning: I have reached the end of \wick with some unclosed contractions on input line 8123."

My code is simply:

`$\wick{\c1 \psi \ket{\c1 p}}$`

I am getting the correct output. But I would like to understand the cause of this error and eliminate it.

Comment: How did you define `\ket`? If you are using the `physics` package then the advice is not to use the `physics` package because it is outdated. The following works without errors or warnings: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\begin{document}
$\wick{\c1 \psi \ket{\c1 p}}$
\end{document}`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex for more information on `\ket`.

Comment: Later I tried with rangle langle rvert and lvert. Still getting the error

Comment: If you still get the error then you need to add a small complete document to your question, similar to the code in the answer below, or the code in my first comment. This document should be as small as possible while still being complete (it should be possible to compile wihtout adding anything) and it should show the error of course. To make such a document you can start with your current code and try to delete as much as you can while the error remains. Then add the code to your question with the `edit` button.

Answer (score 5):

The following code works without the warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\begin{document}
$\wick{\c1\psi\mid \c1 p\rangle}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

It complies perfectly at overleaf:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am still getting the same error

Comment: Does your latex compiler generate the same error/warning from the above five-line code?

Comment: yes, still getting error

Comment: @SamapanBhadury Then you might want to upgrade your tex distribution to the latest version.

Comment: I am using overleaf. :P

Comment: @SamapanBhadury, it compiles perfectly at overleaf. See my updated picture above.